# useEffect runs before props value is received from parent components

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-props

Below useEffect gets executed before props value is received from the parent component. I have noticed that this error happens only once after loading a new app and on reloading same app after getting this error, it works and received value from props.
I would highly appreciate for any suggestion to allow below `useEffect` to run once props value is received.

```
function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("https://........", {
        auth: {
          username: props.username,
          password: props.password,
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [props.username,props.password]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return to omit that specific execution of the useEffect in case `props` aren't defined yet:

```
function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {

    if(!props) { return };

    axios
      .post("https://........", {
        auth: {
          username: props.username,
          password: props.password,
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [props.username,props.password]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Below useEffect gets executed before props value is received from the parent component

This is not true, when the component first mount it receives the props and you should be able to return them in the JSX, and in fact, this happens before `useEffect` runs.
but it is possible that the child component is receiving those props as `undefined`.

example:

```js
const Parent = () => {
 const [myState, setMyState] = useState()

 useEffect(() => {
   setMyState("new value")
 },[])

 return(
   <Child state={myState} />
 )
}
```

Here `Child` will be called with `state` props passed as `undefined` then when `useEffect` of the parent component runs and causes this latter to rerender (since it updates the state).
 Now in this new render `Child` will be called with `state` props passed as `"new value"`, so here in your example, you should have a similar case.

That being said, you probably want to execute the code inside the `useEffect` of the child component only when the props are properly defined

```js
useEffect(() => {
 if(props.username && props.password]) {
   // move your logic here
 }
},[props.username,props.password]])
```

Note that this effect will fire each time `props.username` or `props.password` change value and of course during the first render of the component.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed , yes i do receive 0 as props value and despite using dependency  for props.username and password, useeffect part executed once only at the initial when i receive zero as props value. i have to reload the app indorder to get props value.  this error happens only once after loading app for the first time .

Comment: if `props.username` is updated then `useEffect` should be triggered therefore, if it run only once then `props.username`  is not updated at all, the issue should be in the parent component that provide props to `Home`, so if you can include it in your question maybe this make things clear

Answer (score 0):

**You can add a conditional check within the useEffect to verify if the values exist before making the API call. Here's the modification :**

```
 function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
 // Check if both username and password props are available
   if (props.username && props.password) {
    axios
      .post("https://........", {
         auth: {
          username: props.username,
          password: props.password,
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
   }
 }, [props.username, props.password]);
}
```